# How to get html hidden value in aspx page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

I have a **html** page. I have a `hidden` field and a `button`. On `button` click i am redirecting to a **aspx** page. In **aspx** i am trying to get the `value` of `hidden` field but its showing *null*. Earlier i used form and `action` using `POST` `method` and i was getting the `hidden` field `value` but on `button` click its showing *null* `value`. Here is my code:

I was getting the `hidden` `value` when i used the below code:

```
    <form name='portal' action='http://localhost:53858/Samparka_New_Repo_09022016/b1_land.aspx' method='POST'><body bgcolor='#afd7f4'>
<input type="hidden" name="encdata" runat="server" value="JF7bcrlU9yQyCe">
```

I am not getting the value when i use the below code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="encdata" runat="server" value="JF7bcrlU9yQyCe">
<input type="button" value="Submit" runat="server" onclick="location.href='http://localhost:53858/Samparka_New_Repo_09022016/b1_land.aspx'" />
```

In **aspx** page:

```
string news = Request.Params["encdata"];
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: whats your code behind for the button click event?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` is overriding the `submit`. Remove that and you should be fine (after you also change the type to `submit` as mentioned by DDan).

Check the [Request.HttpMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx) inside the target page, which should now return `GET` instead of `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

youre code behind should be something like

```
Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx?encdata=myVariable");
```

then in the new page you want to be doing something like this, Retrieve Query String!

```
var encData = Request.QueryString["encdata"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Try Catch, ive been working in VB for the last few weeks and forgot I needed the [.. ] rather than (.. )

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit button's type to `submit` and take away the onclick.
Your hidden fields will be submitted to next page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="encdata" runat="server" value="JF7bcrlU9yQyCe">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" />
```